# Alter a Table by adding a new column whose value depends on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table `SMTP` (simplified)

**INITIAL STAGE**

```
| Id |    Server       | ConnectionRequired |
---------------------------------------------
| 0  | smtp.tea.com    |        '1'         |
| 1  | smtp.juice.com  |        '0'         |
| 2  | smtp.coffee.com |        NULL        |
| 3  | smtp.milk.org   |        '1'         |
```

`ConnectionRequired` is a `CHAR(1)`

I am trying to add:

`ConnectionType` of type `INT`

Whose initial value depends on `ConnectionRequired`:

```
'1' becomes 1 otherwise it becomes 0
```

**MIDDLE STAGE**

```
| Id |    Server       | ConnectionRequired | ConnectionType |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 0  | smtp.tea.com    |        '1'         |       1        |
| 1  | smtp.juice.com  |        '0'         |       0        |
| 2  | smtp.coffee.com |        NULL        |       0        |
| 3  | smtp.milk.org   |        '1'         |       1        |
```

THEN I want to `DROP` `ConnectionRequired`

**ENDING STAGE**

```
| Id |    Server       | ConnectionType |
----------------------------------------|
| 0  | smtp.tea.com    |       1        |
| 1  | smtp.juice.com  |       0        |
| 2  | smtp.coffee.com |       0        |
| 3  | smtp.milk.org   |       1        |
```

What I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE SMTP ADD ConnectionType INT NOT NULL

   MIDDLE STAGE.... HAPPENS HERE

ALTER TABLE SMTP DROP COLUMN ConnectionRequired
```

Comment: so you just need the "computation" for a while, but delete the "source column" after computation ?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: You might want to post two different questions then, because the answer is almost certainly going to be different. If someone posts a SQL Server answer, and someone else posts an Oracle answer, how are you going to select "the answer"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point... modifying to SQL-Server only then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and working on both (Sql server and Oracle)

```
update smtp set connectionType = (case when connectionRequired = '1' then 1 else 0 end);
```

Comment: @gtgaxiola so, out of curiosity, how did this possibly work if you did it after `ALTER TABLE SMTP ADD ConnectionType INT NOT NULL`? That couldn't have possibly worked as is (Msg 4901).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the middle stage?  If so, I would try

update smtp set connectionType = decode(connectionRequired, '1', 1, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column with following statement.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ADD ConnectionType INT
```

Update the column with following statement.

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET ConnectionType  = CASE WHEN ConnectionRequired = '1' 
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a column just to update it with data seems like more steps than necessary. I'm not sure if this will incur less log but it seems less likely to cause page splits and extend the size of the table (at least temporarily).

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SMTP
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  [Server] NVARCHAR(256),
  ConnectionRequired CHAR(1)
);

INSERT dbo.SMTP VALUES
(0,'smtp.tea.com   ','1' ),
(1,'smtp.juice.com ','0' ),
(2,'smtp.coffee.com',NULL),
(3,'smtp.milk.org  ','1' );
```

Then you can simply update the data first (to eliminate `NULL`s):

```
UPDATE dbo.SMTP SET ConnectionRequired = '0' WHERE ConnectionRequired IS NULL;
```

Also decide what you want to do for any rows where the data is not `'0'` or `'1'`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SMTP WHERE ConnectionRequired NOT IN ('0','1');
-- UPDATE ...
```

Then change the data type and the nullability:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SMTP ALTER COLUMN ConnectionRequired INT NOT NULL;
```

And rename the column:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.SMTP.ConnectionRequired', N'ConnectionType', N'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `not null` on a new column if the table contains data. You will have to create it first allowing nulls, then run your "middle stage", and then changing the not null constraint. But that will fail as there are nulls in `ConnectionRequired`. How do you want to deal with these?

For the middle stage: use

```
update SMTP set ConnectionType = cast(ConnectionType as int)
```

This will convert `'1'` (char) to `1` (int), `'0'` (char) to `0` (int), and `NULL` (char) to `NULL` (int).