# Replace all email addresses after @ in Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of emails. I want to change all of them to test emails for my test system e.g. John@gmail.com  to john@test.com.
I don't want to use actual emails as it will create problems. Is it possible to change all emails at once in a single query or stored procedure.

Comment: Side-note: never send mails to `@test.com`: It's a real domain and the mails will be received by their mailserver.

Comment: Side note 2: `example.com` *is* a domain intended exactly for these purposes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried this and it worked perfectly.

```
 UPDATE myTable  SET UserEMail = 
 (SELECT SUBSTRING(UserEMail, 0, PATINDEX('%@%',UserEMail)) + '@example.org' 
 from myTable U WHERE U.UserID = myTable.UserID)
```

Comment: Careful with PATINDEX as it will return 0 if there is no match.

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
UPDATE users SET email=REPLACE(email, SUBSTRING(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1),
'example.com')
```

Comment: I think it requires an extension: `Error in query (7): ERROR: function instr(character varying, unknown) does not exist`.. Oops! question is about [tag:tsql] . I have here [tag:psql]

Comment: Love this! Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: Yeah, This questions is useful for other SQL DBMS too!

Answer (score 5):

This one works for me:

UPDATE [TABLE] [EMAIL] = REPLACE([EMAIL], '@company.com', '@test.com')

Answer (score 3):

Add a column in the table structure and define it as: `CONCAT(SUBSTRING([old_column],0,CHARINDEX('@',[old_column])),'@test.com') AS [new_column]`

Refer to M.Ali's answer here to add a new column based on old column:
[Alter a Table by adding a new column whose value depends on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340619/alter-a-table-by-adding-a-new-column-whose-value-depends-on-another-column)

Use `+ and ISNULL` instead of `CONCAT` in case you are using a sql-server version older than `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: why to add a new column? if it is possible in the existing one.

Comment: @Abdul Yes, you can do that as well. I assumed you would need earlier email as well and this might be a good idea to keep earlier emails. Also, in this case use CHARINDEX instead of PATINDEX, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE employees SET email=REPLACE(email, SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1),'test.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `STUFF` or `LEFT` string functions. Try this

```
DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(200) = 'John@gmail.com'

SELECT Stuff(@emails, Charindex('@', @emails), Len(@emails), '') + '@test.com'

SELECT LEFT(@emails, Charindex('@', @emails)-1) + '@test.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet -

```
create table #email (emailid varchar(20));
    insert into #email
    select 'john@gmail.com' union
    select 'john@yahoo.co.in' union
    select 'deepanshu.kalra@outlook.com'
    select * from #email;
    select replace(emailid,left(substring(emailid,charindex('@',emailid)+1,len(emailid)),charindex('.',substring(emailid,charindex('@',emailid)+1,len(emailid)))-1),'test' from #email;
```

Comment: my email id is deepanshu`.`kalra@outlook`.`com. Also why are we using PATINNDEX to find a character?

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra - thanks for identifying for the miss, changed the logic now.

Answer (score -1):

All data is potentially valuable. If you need to ensure emails can NEVER be sent out from a test system, I suggest ... SET email = 'XXX' + email + 'XXX'.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.